# object detection with contours in region of interest

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I want to use contours for object detection.I can separate object from background .I have a bounding box in the center of image.I want to when the object was in the bounding box, detect it.I use`

```
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size();j++)  {  
        cout << contours[i][j] << endl;
        // ...
```

for show all contours in i & j.and use this code

```
for(int x = 405; x < 455; x++) {
    for (int y = 210; y < 280; y++) {
        if (contours[i, j] == contours[x, y])
        // ...
```

for detect object in region of interest.but when I run the program ,my code have break in
`if (contours[i, j] == contours[x, y])`
.do you have any idea to solve my problem?Thank you for your help.

```
`//draw each contour with a random color
int idx = 0;
for (; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0]){ Scalar color(rand() & 255, rand() & 255);
    if (contourArea(contours[idx]) < 20)
        drawContours(dst2, contours, idx, color, CV_FILLED);}
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size();j++){
        //  cout << contours[i][j] << endl;
        for (int x = 405; x < 455; x++) {
            for (int y = 210; y < 280; y++){
                if (contours[i][j] == contours[x][y]) {
                    rectangle(frame, rectangle2, Scalar(255, 255, 255)) } 
}
    } 
        }`
```

I have two bounding box and I want when object was in smaller bounding box than the other bounding box hide.

Comment: shouldn't it be `contours[i][j] == contours[x][y]`?

Comment: I tested this but there was no change at the result

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: There was no error.my program build successfully but when i run it,Code execution stops.

Comment: Be very wary of C++'s [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). `contours[i, j]` almost certainly does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You need to tell us _where_ the code stops. Have you run this through a debugger? You haven't given us nearly enough code to diagnose the specific cause of the failure.

Comment: I use `contours[i][j]` but there was no change at the result

Comment: I said that where  my code stops.I use visual studio 2015

Comment: In your last code block do you want
`for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size();j++){`    instead of
`for (int j = 0; j < contours[j].size();j++){`    ?

Comment: @brad sorry. that was a Typographical mistakes only.no change at the result

Comment: @rook I use contours[i][j] but there was no change at the result.I I've added some of my code again.for solve this problem if you need more code tell me but I said that I have break in `contours[i][j] == contours[x][y]`

Comment: Ok, I suspect that your problem is that you're trying to treat `contours` as if it were an image that you can index with `x` and `y` co-ordinates, when in fact it is a collection of zero or more contours, where each contour is represented by some number of points. The number and length of each contour is not fixed, and so `contours[x][y]` is amost certainly trying to index into a nonexistent contour line or point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the block of code that is probably at fault.

```
for (int x = 405; x < 455; x++) {
    for (int y = 210; y < 280; y++) {
        if (contours[i][j] == contours[x][y]) {
            rectangle(frame, rectangle2, Scalar(255, 255, 255)) } 
    }
}
```

The problematic bit of this is `contours[x][y]`, because it assumes you have (at least) 455 contours, and that the 50 contours from the 405th onwards have (at least) 280 points. This is almost certainly not what you wanted to do, and given that your program crashes, it definitely means you haven't found enough contours, or contours of sufficient length for this to make sense.

`contours` is not an image with x and y coordinates, but a list of zero or more boundaries, where each boundary has some number of points (presumably at least 3, but I don't know for sure). `countours[i][j]` is fine, because you've already checked that `i` and `j` are in bounds in the enclosing `for` loops.

I can't suggest what you should do instead, because your code has a lot of typographical errors (not all of which you have fixed) and your question is unclear. I suspect you'd need to start by taking the point found at `contours[i][j]` and seeing whether it lay within your ROI. You don't need to loop over `x` and `y` values to do this.

Really, you should have discovered this already by using a debugger, checking the actual boundaries of `contours` and so on. I don't know what build environment and options you're using, but plenty of them support raising helpful debug assertions and meaningful exceptions when you try accessing out of container bounds. You should use these sorts of systems to help you. You shoudl also turn on more compiler warnings as your code is *littered* with mistakes any one of which could cause you problems and has made diagnosing this issue more diffiocult that it needed to be.

Comment: good answer.You're right.Thanks a lot.but if I use Harriscorners for object detect,can I detect object in region of interest?

Comment: Without knowing more about the images you're working with and the objects you're trying to detect, I can't say. There are certainly lots of cases where a corner detector can help.

Comment: the object that I'm trying to detect have Differences from background.for example my object is Brighter or darker from background and the size of object is not very lorg

Comment: Against some backgrounds, such as ones with lots of noise or other items you don't care about, you'll find that the corner detector will have many responses, most of which you won't want. You'd need to combine it with some other way of characterising the object (which again, would depend on the nature of that object).